# Mysterious offset in absolute positioned divs

Tags: html, css

So I have my widget working perfectly except for one ridiculously confusing detail. At some point during development the `backside` of each `flipper` got offset during its flip and I can't for the life of me figure out how.

EDIT: ADDING A SNIPPET

```js
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("flipper");
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("cardtext");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
  list[i].style.display = "none";
for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
  cells[j].getElementsByClassName("frontside")[0].textContent = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)].textContent;
  cells[j].getElementsByClassName("backside")[0].textContent = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)].textContent;
}

function replaceCardText(c) {
  var randText = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  if (cells[c].classList.contains("flip"))
    cells[c].getElementsByClassName("frontside")[0].textContent = list[randText].textContent;
  else
    cells[c].getElementsByClassName("backside")[0].textContent = list[randText].textContent;
}

setInterval(function() {
  var randCell = Math.floor(Math.random() * cells.length);
  cells[randCell].classList.toggle("flip");
  setTimeout(function() {
    replaceCardText(randCell);
  }, 400);
}, 750);
```

```css
#symptoms {}

#grid {
  margin: 0 5%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}


/*#grid > div > div {
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }*/

#grid .flipper {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

#grid .frontside,
.backside {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #00494F;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #00494F;
}

#grid .frontside {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

#grid .backside {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  background: #00A3C4;
}

#grid .cardtext {}
```

```html
<section id="upper">
  <div id="symptoms">
    <h3>Suffer No Longer!</h3>
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 style="text-align: right">Call Your Coach!</h3>
    <section>
      <div class="cardtext">total weight gain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">beer belly</div>
      <div class="cardtext">heavy hips</div>
      <div class="cardtext">loss of waistline</div>
      <div class="cardtext">pasta cravings</div>
      <div class="cardtext">sugar cravings</div>
      <div class="cardtext">anxiety</div>
      <div class="cardtext">loss of libido</div>
      <div class="cardtext">depression</div>
      <div class="cardtext">bread cravings</div>
      <div class="cardtext">stress overload</div>
      <div class="cardtext">depression</div>
      <div class="cardtext">chocolate cravings</div>
      <div class="cardtext">crave salty snacks</div>
      <div class="cardtext">fight fatigue</div>
      <div class="cardtext">night sweats</div>
      <div class="cardtext">can't fall asleep</div>
      <div class="cardtext">bloating</div>
      <div class="cardtext">shortness of breath</div>
      <div class="cardtext">hot flashes</div>
      <div class="cardtext">can't stay asleep</div>
      <div class="cardtext">sleep apnea</div>
      <div class="cardtext">belching</div>
      <div class="cardtext">cramping &amp; gas</div>
      <div class="cardtext">sinus issues</div>
      <div class="cardtext">low back pain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">mid-back pain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">rt-shoulder pain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">knee pain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">cold susceptibility</div>
      <div class="cardtext">insulin resistance</div>
      <div class="cardtext">slow metabolism</div>
      <div class="cardtext">high cholesterol</div>
      <div class="cardtext">high blood pressure</div>
      <div class="cardtext">ovarian cysts</div>
      <div class="cardtext">allergies</div>
      <div class="cardtext">moon face</div>
      <div class="cardtext">puffy eyes</div>
      <div class="cardtext">thinning hair</div>
      <div class="cardtext">brown skin spots</div>
      <div class="cardtext">yellow eyes</div>
      <div class="cardtext">midriff bulge</div>
      <div class="cardtext">dark circles</div>
      <div class="cardtext">hair loss</div>
      <div class="cardtext">thinning eyebrows</div>
      <div class="cardtext">red skin spots</div>
      <div class="cardtext">vaginal dryness</div>
      <div class="cardtext">ridged nails</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

[offset panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOSRL.png)

You can see from the snip that the blue rect is offset by roughly two pixels upward.

I have been maddeningly poking things through the inspector and I can't find a single property that changes the position of the `backside` divs at all. Any clues?

Comment: Is it not just the 3D affect? Sorry, I can't try it out right now.

Comment: cannot reproduce the bug from your code. Can you provide a code snippet/jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: I don't see the problem on my computer when running what you posted. One suggestion, wrap the entire code with a parent div like `<div class="container">`, and make the `.container {position:relative; }`.

Comment: @shaochuancs I added a snippet and I can see the exact issue manifested when I run the snippet I attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is offset because `.frontside` and `.backside` div's `box-sizing` value is `content-box` (the default value). Thus, as you define their `width` and `height` as 100%, their "content-area" already takes 175px*50px. As they also have 2px border, the whole box size would be 179px*54px. The offset does not appear before rotate because `.flipper`'s position is `absolute`, and nearby `.flipper` override each other, makes it feel like "normal". However, after one `flipper` is rotated, the offset would appear.

You can give `.frontsize` and `.backside` a big padding (30px for example) to see what happens.

The fix is simple: define the `box-sizing` as `border-box`:

```
#grid .frontside, .backside {
  ...
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```js
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("flipper");
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("cardtext");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
  list[i].style.display = "none";
for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
  cells[j].getElementsByClassName("frontside")[0].textContent = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)].textContent;
  cells[j].getElementsByClassName("backside")[0].textContent = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)].textContent;
}

function replaceCardText(c) {
  var randText = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  if (cells[c].classList.contains("flip"))
    cells[c].getElementsByClassName("frontside")[0].textContent = list[randText].textContent;
  else
    cells[c].getElementsByClassName("backside")[0].textContent = list[randText].textContent;
}

setInterval(function() {
  var randCell = Math.floor(Math.random() * cells.length);
  cells[randCell].classList.toggle("flip");
  setTimeout(function() {
    replaceCardText(randCell);
  }, 400);
}, 750);
```

```css
#symptoms {}

#grid {
  margin: 0 5%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
  perspective: 500px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}


/*#grid > div > div {
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }*/

#grid .flipper {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

#grid .frontside,
.backside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #00494F;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #00494F;
}

#grid .frontside {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

#grid .backside {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  background: #00A3C4;
}

#grid .cardtext {}
```

```html
<section id="upper">
  <div id="symptoms">
    <h3>Suffer No Longer!</h3>
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flipper">
        <div class="frontside"></div>
        <div class="backside"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3 style="text-align: right">Call Your Coach!</h3>
    <section>
      <div class="cardtext">total weight gain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">beer belly</div>
      <div class="cardtext">heavy hips</div>
      <div class="cardtext">loss of waistline</div>
      <div class="cardtext">pasta cravings</div>
      <div class="cardtext">sugar cravings</div>
      <div class="cardtext">anxiety</div>
      <div class="cardtext">loss of libido</div>
      <div class="cardtext">depression</div>
      <div class="cardtext">bread cravings</div>
      <div class="cardtext">stress overload</div>
      <div class="cardtext">depression</div>
      <div class="cardtext">chocolate cravings</div>
      <div class="cardtext">crave salty snacks</div>
      <div class="cardtext">fight fatigue</div>
      <div class="cardtext">night sweats</div>
      <div class="cardtext">can't fall asleep</div>
      <div class="cardtext">bloating</div>
      <div class="cardtext">shortness of breath</div>
      <div class="cardtext">hot flashes</div>
      <div class="cardtext">can't stay asleep</div>
      <div class="cardtext">sleep apnea</div>
      <div class="cardtext">belching</div>
      <div class="cardtext">cramping &amp; gas</div>
      <div class="cardtext">sinus issues</div>
      <div class="cardtext">low back pain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">mid-back pain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">rt-shoulder pain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">knee pain</div>
      <div class="cardtext">cold susceptibility</div>
      <div class="cardtext">insulin resistance</div>
      <div class="cardtext">slow metabolism</div>
      <div class="cardtext">high cholesterol</div>
      <div class="cardtext">high blood pressure</div>
      <div class="cardtext">ovarian cysts</div>
      <div class="cardtext">allergies</div>
      <div class="cardtext">moon face</div>
      <div class="cardtext">puffy eyes</div>
      <div class="cardtext">thinning hair</div>
      <div class="cardtext">brown skin spots</div>
      <div class="cardtext">yellow eyes</div>
      <div class="cardtext">midriff bulge</div>
      <div class="cardtext">dark circles</div>
      <div class="cardtext">hair loss</div>
      <div class="cardtext">thinning eyebrows</div>
      <div class="cardtext">red skin spots</div>
      <div class="cardtext">vaginal dryness</div>
      <div class="cardtext">ridged nails</div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Okay, so am I seeing this correctly? Just adding `box-sizing`? Do you mind explaining the issue and solution?

Comment: @PaulGarrett yes, the fix is just adding `box-sizing`. I've added some explanation.

Comment: That's an awesome explanation. Thanks a ton for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should'nt be using multiple ID's for your grid elements, instead give them classes. Then you could try to give your grid element the property: "display:table" to see if that helps anything, and lastly you could try to define a "relative" parent element for your asolutely positioned .frontside and .backside to see if that sorts the bugging out.